# Two buttons to change to an other Activity on an Android App (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm learning how to create apps with Android Studio, and I can't change to an other activity with 2 buttons. For example, I've got the button contact, which permits me to go to the contact_list class, and the button msg, which permits me to go to the message_enregistre class.

Problem: the contact button works but the msg button doesn't. When I press the msg button, the application goes back to the main_activity. I think that my AndroidManifest.xml is fine.

But I don't know why the msg button doesn't work. Can you help me please ?

The parametres.java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class parametres extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parametres);
    final Button contact =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent act1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), contact_list.class);
            startActivity(act1);

        }
    });

    final Button msg =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view2)
        {
            Intent act2 = new Intent(view2.getContext(), message_enregistre.class);
            startActivity(act2);

        }
    });
}

}
```

And the AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.baptiste.saveme">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".parametres"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".contact_list"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".message_enregistre"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your message_enregistre class

Comment: check `setContentView(R.layout.*);` in your `message_enregistre` class I think you have given `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` inside `message_enregistre` class.

Comment: This part of my code is good, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting multiple OnClickListeners(), which could be the source of your problem. I suggest you change your code to.

```
public class parametres extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parametres);
    final Button contact =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    contact.setOnClickListener(this);

    final Button msg =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    msg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

 @Override
 public void onClick(view v) {
     Intent i;
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button3:
        i  = new Intent(parametres.this, contact_list.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.button4:
         i = new Intent(parametres.this, message_enregistre.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure  that is the problem, is legal to create any new instance for View.OnClickListener as you want, is not properly but its works.

Comment: Fine, I'll check this today.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The function setOnClickListener didn't accept the parameter "this". Do you have a solution please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Ok fine, I find the solution :)
Thanks for your help :)